# Unreal C++ - Changing specific Static Mesh location by code

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I'm new to Unreal Engine development and I'm struggling to do something which would be trivial in Unity.

I'm following this [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/31800833-unreal-engine-5-tutorial-for-beginners-getting-started).

I'm trying to do the "Rotating the propeller" section without the use of Blueprint nodes.

The Blueprint nodes can reference the static meshes individually but I can't find any C++ method that would do the same thing. All examples I found online make use of acquiring the actor through a component and rotating the actor. This way, it would rotate the whole submarine and not just the propeller as intended.

Like this (Snippet from an ActorComponent code):

```
RotationTime += DeltaTime;
RotationTime = fmin(RotationTime, TimeToRotate);
auto actor = GetOwner();
float alpha = RotationTime / TimeToRotate;
FRotator rotator = FMath::Lerp(FRotator(0, 0, 0), FRotator(0, 90, 0), alpha);
actor->SetActorRotation(rotator);
```

In Unity this can be accomplished by declaring a GameObject in the component and modifying its transform. How can I achieve this in Unreal? I'm composing the static meshes in a Blueprint Class and I can modify their transforms in the Blueprint editor and they show up correctly in the game. I saw in a video tutorial that this would be a good case for using animations but I don't see the reason why something so simple can't be done strictly in code.

Answer (score 0):

In blueprints, these static meshes are actually static mesh components. You would probably want to do the same thing in C++, so you can create component

```
UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere)
    UStaticMeshComponent* StaticMesh;
```

You can then spawn the component in constructor in the .cpp file

```
    StaticMesh = CreateDefaultSubobject<UStaticMeshComponent>(TEXT("Rotating Part"));
```

then the rotation part in tick (I made simpler case)

```
Alpha = DeltaTime * Speed;
FRotator Rotation = FRotator(0, 0, Alpha);
StaticMesh->AddLocalRotation(Rotation);
```